# How to speed up loading of maps on low budget device (like raspberry pi)

Tags: performance, raspberry-pi, maps, here-api

I have an issue that rendering of here maps via Maps API for JavaScript took far too long on a low budget device like a raspberry pi.

Loading of this [simple example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b) takes more than 10 seconds to load (4 CPU cores at 100%). Similar Maps with Google Maps or Openstreetmap took less than 1 seconds on the same device, same browser (Chromium) and same internet connection.
It looks like the standard js are too heavy for a small device. How do I optimize the query to speed up loading time?

Comment: If you don't need vector tiles, you could try to get raster tiles instead see if it improves: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/raster.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need vector tiles, you could try to get raster tiles instead see if it improves: developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/raster.html